# Showing a certain operator on a set of holomorphic functions attains its supremum

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

> Let $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be open and connected, and fix $a_1, a_2 \in G$. Let $\mathcal{F} := \{f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}: f$ is holomorphic and $|f(z)| \leq 1 \}$.
>
> Define $\Phi: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $$\Phi (f) := |f(a_1)| + |f'(a_2)|.$$  Show that $\Phi$ has a maximum, i.e., that there is $f_0 \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\Phi(f_0) = \sup \{\Phi(f): f\in \mathcal{F}\}$.

It should be possible to write the proof with just complex analysis tools and the basic functional analysis needed to prove Arzelà-Ascoli.  Let $\rho$ denote the distance for $C(G,\mathbb{C})$, as defined in pg. 142-148 of *Functions of One Complex Variable I*, 2nd edition, by Conway.  We can endow $\mathcal{F}$ with $\rho$.

One idea is to show $\Phi$ is continuous and $\mathcal{F}$ is compact.  If these two things are true, the conclusion would follow immediately.

Another idea is to construct $f_0$ somehow.  Since $|f(a_1)| \leq 1$ $\forall f \in \mathcal{F}$, we could focus on making $|f_0'(a_2)|$ maximal.

Also, it'd be helpful to understand what the operator $\Phi$ is actually measuring.

Comment: Do you know Montel's theorem? And Weierstraß' theorem concerning the locally uniform convergence of the derivatives of a locally uniformly convergent sequence of holomorphic functions?

Comment: I do know Montel's theorem, and I know Weierstraß's in essence, but not in name.  As for $\rho$, I could not define it fully in the comments, hence why I referenced the chapter where Conway develops it.  I think it's sufficient to know that it's a distance on $C(G,\mathbb{C})$ with some nice properties.  One particularly nice property is that you can relate it back to a distance $d(f(z_1),f(z_2)) := |f(z_1)-f(z_2)|$ on compact subsets of $G$-- which it seems Daniel Fischer explains in the comments to his answer.

Comment: @Michael: [here][1] is the Google ebook of Conway.  You can't access the whole book, but you may get lucky and be able to view pg. 142-148, which are of relevance in defining norms on $C(G,\mathbb{C})$.


  [1]: http://books.google.com/books/about/Functions_of_One_Complex_Variable_I.html?id=9LtfZr1snG0C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One idea is to show $\Phi$ is continuous and $\mathcal{F}$ is compact. If these two things are true, the conclusion would follow immediately.

These things are true, if we take the standard topology - the topology of locally uniform convergence - on $\mathscr{O}(G)$.

With the standard topology, the subspace topology induced by $C(G)$, the space $\mathscr{O}(G)$ of holomorphic functions on the domain $G$ is a Fréchet-Montel space. That is, a Fréchet space in which every closed and bounded subset is compact. The latter is basically the content of Montel's little theorem, a locally bounded family of holomorphic functions is normal. The set

$$\mathcal{F} = \left\{ f \in \mathscr{O}(G) : \bigl(\forall z\in G\bigr)\bigl( \lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant 1\bigr)\right\}$$

is clearly bounded, and since the inequality is non-strict, also closed. Hence is is compact.

The map $f \mapsto \lvert f(a_1)\rvert$ is even continuous on $C(G)$, hence also on the subspace $\mathscr{O}(G)$.

The map $f \mapsto \lvert f'(a_2)\rvert$ is continuous on $\mathscr{O}(G)$ due to the integral formula for the derivatives, which gives a bound for the values of $f'$ on any compact subset $K\subset G$ in terms of a bound for the values of $f$ on any compact neighbourhood $K' \subset G$ of $K$.

So $\Phi$ is the sum of two continuous functions, hence continuous.

However, I expect that the exercise was intended to be solved with less functional analytic arguments.

By the classical Montel theorem, the family $\mathcal{F}$ is normal, since it is (uniformly, even) bounded.

Then consider a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions in $\mathcal{F}$ with

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \Phi(f_n) = \sup \{ \Phi(f) : f \in \mathcal{F}\}.$$

By the normality of $\mathcal{F}$, we can assume that $f_n$ converges locally uniformly on $G$ to a function $f$. By a theorem of Weierstraß, the locally uniform limit of holomorphic functions is holomorphic, and clearly $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$ for all $z\in G$, so $f\in \mathcal{F}$.

By another theorem of Weierstraß, if a sequence of holomorphic functions $(f_n)$ converges locally uniformly, then the sequence $(f_n')$ of derivatives also converges locally uniformly, and of course to the derivative of $\lim f_n$.

Thus we have $f(a_1) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(a_1)$ and $f'(a_2) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n'(a_2)$, and therefore

$$\Phi(f) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \Phi(f_n) = \sup \{\Phi(g) : g \in \mathcal{F}\},$$

i.e. the supremum is attained.

Comment: @Michael The space $\mathscr{O}(G)$ is (in the standard topology, as mentioned) endowed with the seminorms $p_K(f) := \sup \{ \lvert f(z)\rvert : z\in K\}$, where $K$ ranges over the compact subsets of $G$. That gives you the usual concepts of convergence and boundedness in locally convex spaces.

Comment: @Michael That doesn't quite work, since there are holomorphic functions that are unbounded on $G$, you need to take the supremum over a (relatively) compact subset, and then consider the family of these (semi-)norms. But then you have the convergence of the derivative along with the function built into the distance (by the Cauchy estimates, you also have it built in for $\rho_K(f) = \sup_K \lvert f(z)\rvert$, but not explicitly). The problem then is to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is compact. Your seminorms directly give you the equicontinuity of $\mathcal{F}$, and closedness is simple.

Comment: But then, for convergence in your seminorms, you also need the locally uniform convergence of the derivatives, and to get that, you need the Cauchy estimates for the second derivatives (which then give the equicontinuity of $\mathcal{F}' = \{ f' : f\in\mathcal{F}\}$) or Weierstraß' theorem [which is a consequence of the Cauchy estimates].

Comment: @DanielFischer: Just to clarify for future readers, $\mathscr{O}(G) = H(G) = Hol(G)$, i.e., the space of holomorphic functions on $G$. And $C(G)$ is the set of continuous functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$ (what I called $C(G,\mathbb{C})$).  Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I tend to leave out the codomain for $C(X)$ when it's $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Maybe misapplied laziness.

Comment: The functional analysis argument looks sound to me.  Regarding the complex argument: I'm concerned about the line "Then consider a sequence $(f_n)$ of functions in $\mathcal{F}$ with $\lim_{n\to \infty} \Phi(f_n) = \sup \{ \Phi(f) : f \in \mathcal{F}\}.$"  Before we can choose such a sequence $(f_n)$, I think it's important to note that $\sup \{ \Phi(f) : f \in \mathcal{F}\}$ exists and is finite (which follows directly from $|f(a_1)| \leq 1$ and Cauchy estimates on $|f'(a_2)|$, for all $f \in \mathcal{F}$).

Comment: Even if the supremum were infinite, a sequence in $\mathcal{F}$ with $\Phi(f_n) \to \sup \{ \Phi(f) : f\in \mathcal{F}\}$ always exists. The finiteness is a consequence of the normality then.

Comment: I see.  One last question: the normality of $\mathcal{F}$ gives us a subsequence of $(f_n)$ that converges to some $f$, not necessarily the whole sequence.  Are you retroactively/implicitly choosing $(f_n)$ to be this subsequence?

Comment: Yes. Take any maximising sequence, and extract a compactly convergent subsequence, then rename and pretend it was your originally chosen sequence.

Comment: So I deleted my comments.